# Removing incremental elements in a list and compressing them into one element

Tags: python

I have a list created from reading a file that looks similar to this:

```
entries = ['Entry #1', 'Entry #3 (2019)', 'Entry #4', 'Entry #6', 'Entry #7', 'Entry #8', 'Entry #9']
```

I'd like for the list to look something like this:

```
entries = ['Entry #1', 'Entry #3 - #4 (2019)', 'Entry #6 - #9']
```

My programming knowledge is still lacking as I'm still learning, so it would be great if I could get some help. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the criteria to transform the first list into the second?

Comment: I would start with a list like `[1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, compress that, then generate the list of `Entry` strings. (I'm not entirely sure how you would work `'(2019)'` in to that process, though. Merging `3 (2019)` and `4` already looks kind of wrong.)

Comment: By "wrong", I mean you can't recover the original list from the merged list, because you wouldn't seem to know which elements of the range did and did not have the `(2019)` modifier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `map` function on a list to apply functions to all of its elements. Use this to create (1) a list of the numbers of the entries and (2) a list of any extra info which was at the end of the entries:

```py
nums = list (map(lambda a: int(a[7]), entries))
extras = list(map(lambda a: a[8:], entries))
```

This gives `nums` = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9] and `extras` = ['', ' (2019)', '', '', '', '', '']

Now iterate through the numbers between the first and last numbers in the `nums` list, keeping track of the start and end of each group and updating it according to whether or not the next consecutive number is in the `nums` list

```py
result = []
num = start = nums[0]
end = num - 1
while num <= nums[-1]:
    if num in nums:
        end += 1
        num += 1
    else:
        if start == end:
            result.append(f"Entry #{start}" + extras[nums.index(start)])
        else:
            result.append(f"Entry #{start} - #{end}" + "".join(extras[nums.index(start):nums.index(end) + 1]))
        # Reset start, num and end to the next number in the list
        start = num = nums[nums.index(num - 1) + 1]
        end = num - 1

# Add the last group
if start == end:
    result.append(f"Entry #{start}" + extras[nums.index(start)])
else:
    result.append(f"Entry #{start} - #{end}" + "".join(extras[nums.index(start):nums.index(end) + 1]))
```

This gives `result` = ['Entry #1', 'Entry #3 - #4 (2019)', 'Entry #6 - #9']

Completed code:

```py
entries = ['Entry #1', 'Entry #3 (2019)', 'Entry #4', 'Entry #6', 'Entry #7', 'Entry #8', 'Entry #9']

nums = list(map(lambda a: int(a[7]), entries))
extras = list(map(lambda a: a[8:], entries))

result = []
num = start = nums[0]
end = num - 1
while num <= nums[-1]:
    if num in nums:
        end += 1
        num += 1
    else:
        if start == end:
            result.append(f"Entry #{start}" + extras[nums.index(start)])
        else:
            result.append(f"Entry #{start} - #{end}" + "".join(extras[nums.index(start):nums.index(end) + 1]))
        # Reset start, num and end to the next number in the list
        start = num = nums[nums.index(num - 1) + 1]
        end = num - 1

# Add the last group
if start == end:
    result.append(f"Entry #{start}" + extras[nums.index(start)])
else:
    result.append(f"Entry #{start} - #{end}" + "".join(extras[nums.index(start):nums.index(end) + 1]))
    
print(result)
```

Comment: With `['Entry #1', 'Entry #3 (2019)', 'Entry #4 (2019)', 'Entry #6', 'Entry #7', 'Entry #8', 'Entry #9']` I get `['Entry #1', 'Entry #3 - #4 (2019) (2019)', 'Entry #6 - #9']`. The double "(2019)" looks strange, but at least you don't lose any information. The asker should clarify their wanted result.

Comment: If you have to use a `lambda` to use `map`, you may as well just use a list comprehension. Among other reasons, it will actually *work* (your code won't on Python 3, as `map` doesn't make `list`s on Py3).

Comment: Oops, I added list functions around the maps in my actual code file but forgot to change it on the answer. I'll do that now.